# Display image from a folder outside the web root directory public_html

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I want to upload an image in a folder that outside public_html mean public_html and upload(my image folder name) are parallel to each other
my directory structure like

public_html
     website
upload
    images

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
include 'connect.php';

$title=$_REQUEST['pt'];
$brand=strtoupper($_REQUEST['b']);
$author=$_REQUEST['authod'];
$des=$_REQUEST['des'];
$category=$_REQUEST['c'];
$sub_category=$_REQUEST['s'];
$oprice=$_REQUEST['o'];
$sprice=$_REQUEST['sp'];
$nm =$_FILES['f']['name'];
$fol =time()."_".rand(0,99)."_".$nm;

$path="/home/mydomain/upload/".$fol;



$tmp=$_FILES['f']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path );


$sq = mysql_query("insert into 
bachhaoffer(id,title,brand,author,des,category,scategory,oprice,sprice,image) values ('','$title','$brand', '$author' , '$des','$category','$sub_category','$oprice','$sprice','$path')");
if($sq)
{

echo "<script>window.location.href='../'</script>";
}else
{
echo "<script>alert('no')</script>";
}
?>
```

Upload Is working fine but when I want to display image then show me an error.
please give me the right way to show an image.

I am Try to fetch image url and display image
so I create file with name img.php

```
<?php
$mime_type = mime_content_type("/image_path/{$_GET['file']}");
header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
readfile("/image_path/{$_GET['file']}");
?>
```

and display using

```
<img src="img.php?file=photo.jpg" />
```

Show error like
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mydomain/public_html/img.php:1) in /home/mydomain/public_html/img.php on line 3

Comment: what error is it showing you?

Comment: i am simple apply code

Comment: <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" this is my $image variable access from database

Comment: @Mo'menMohamed where is duplicate question

Comment: my problem not same 
     
my problem is my site folder is place in public_html and image home/mydomain/upload  
     
upload and public_html folder are parallel

Answer (score 1):

direct path won't work cause you can't get content from outside of root folder. 
Another way is Read image file in php script from server dir path and serve file using `header`. 
First Create `img.php`
Write this code

```
    <?php
       $mime_type = mime_content_type("/image_path/{$_GET['file']}");
       header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
       readfile("/image_path/{$_GET['file']}");
    ?>
```

After than use `<img src="img.php?file=photo.jpg" />` on your img tag in html. Hope it will work.

Comment: This is just an example. You can use jpg or png whatever.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mydonain/public_html/img.php:1) in /home/mydomain/public_html/img.php on line 3